# No DNS But Internet Access

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dns, ping

Today while using a Wifi Analyzer I noted that I had 100% loss of ping packets to the DNS Server.  To try to isolate the problem I hard wired my computer to my cable modem bypassing my wireless router.  I then executed ipconfig /all to see all of my DNS IP addresses.  I then pinged each one of the DNS addresses but noted that all of the DNS IP numbers timed out.  I contacted Comcast and they said that my DNS configuration needed to be reconfigured.

What I do not understand is why I was able to browse the internet without a DNS.  Furthermore at the DOS prompt I was able to ping some internet IP addresses successfully.  Without a DNS server, shouldn't these requests have gone "Timed Out" as there was no DNS resolution?  My pings were in the form of ping www.internetsite.com.

I cleared my ip address via ipconfig /release for both IPV4 and IPV6.  I also cleared my DNS via ipconfig /flushdns.  I re-registered everything with new IP addresses.

Comment: Try using `nslookup` to check if your DNS is running. Not all servers respond to pings

Answer (score 1):

Well, you did run `ipconfig /flushdns` after reconnecting... i.e. you flushed the **DNS cache** of your local machine.

I suppose you got lucky and only ping'ed servers you had already accessed before your ISP reconfigured the DNS.